# Modify zsh commands to forward errors

Tags: error-handling, pipe, zsh

I would like to modify one of my recent Bash aliases to forward errors. Here is the alias:

```
alias makecclip=
     "make |& tee >(sed \"s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g\"  |
     egrep \":[0-9]+:[0-9]+: error\" | cut -d : -f1,2,3 |
     head -n 1 | xargs -0 echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard &&
     xclip -selection clipboard -o)
```

This code displays the results of a C++ compilation, and then removes formatting and displays and adds to the clipboard the first error location (if there is any).

However, I would like to use this code like this:

```
makecclip && bin/someexecutablecreated
```

This though ruins the `&&` operator, since it always runs bin/someexecutablecreated even when there is a compilation error present. How can I add modifications to the code to set the error flag, when the error list (the things saved to clipboard and echoed) is not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can address your issue by using the `PIPESTATUS` internal variable (this variable has other names in non-bash shells). This allows to have an history of exit statuses of commands passed by pipe.

---

You precised in the comments that you didn't use `bash`, but used `zsh` instead. As such, some of the syntax of my solution has to be changed, as they handle the `PIPESTATUS` variable differently.

In bash, you use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`, whereas you'll use `${pipestatus[1]}` in zsh.

---

A first approach, using your existing alias, could be as follow :

```
makecclip && [ "${pipestatus[1]}" -eq "0" ] && echo "ok"
```

This runs the `echo` command only if `"${pipestatus[1]}"` is equal to 0 (no errors during make)

A more convenient solution would be to use a function instead of an alias for `makecclip`. In your `~/.bashrc` file, you could write :

```
makecclip () {
    make |& tee >(sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" | egrep ":[0-9]+:[0-9]+: error" | cut -d : -f1,2,3 | head -n 1 | xargs -0 echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard && xclip -selection clipboard -o)
    return "${pipestatus[1]}"
}
```

Now, `makecclip && echo "ok"` will work as expected.

Test cases :

```
#!/bin/zsh
#do not run this test if there is an existing makefile in your current directory
rm -f makefile
makecclip () {
    make |& tee >(sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" | egrep ":[0-9]+:[0-9]+: error" | cut -d : -f1,2,3 | head -n 1 | xargs -0 echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard && xclip -selection clipboard -o)

    # this part is only present to check the pipestatus values during the tests.
    # In the real function, I wrote 'return ${pipestatus[1]}' instead. 
    a=(${pipestatus[@]})
    echo ${a[@]}
    return ${a[1]}
}

echo "# no makefile"
makecclip && echo "ok"
echo -e "\n# empty makefile"
touch makefile
makecclip && echo "ok"
echo -e "\n# dummy makefile entry"
echo -e 'a:\n\t@echo "inside makefile"' > makefile
makecclip && echo "ok"
echo -e "\n# program with error makefile"
echo -e "int main(){error; return 0;}" > target.cc
echo -e 'a:\n\tgcc target.cc' > makefile
makecclip && echo "ok"
```

Output :

```
$ ./test.sh
# no makefile
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
2 0

# empty makefile
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
2 0

# dummy makefile entry
inside makefile
0 0
ok

# program with error
gcc target.cc
target.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
target.cc:1:12: error: ‘error’ was not declared in this scope
 int main(){error; return 0;}
            ^
makefile:2: recipe for target 'a' failed
make: *** [a] Error 1
target.cc:1:12
2 0
```

Comment: I tried it, but it does not seem to work. I think it is actually the make that would change the pipestatus, but there I have to redirect the error too. Did it work with your tests?

Comment: yes, it worked just fine on my computer. I've edited my question to add the tests I've used.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi sorry, it took me a while to formalize my test cases in a script. You can see the test I ran and the output I got.

Comment: The test you provided gives the same output for me too, but it does not work on normal compilation targets.

Comment: Also, when I source my .zshrc (.bashrc) file it times out on your function. It interprets it opening a new terminal though.

Comment: I'll add a counter-example to your answer.

Comment: ok, this is why I specified my solution worked for `bash` ONLY (as your question was tagged with it). `bash` and  `zsh` have different internal variables. I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: For some reason it still does not work... :((
It always runs the command after && for me.
Update, only the script failed with pipestatus[@], not the pipestatus[1] one, sorry.

Comment: Well, sometimes it still does not work, but I can't figure out, why.

Comment: I think it will depend on the context. Does it fail when you call it from your console ? from a script with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang ? from a script with a `#!/bin/zsh` shebang ? from both contexts ?